# In any of the Highlander movies (except #2), is there a clear implication that Only One remains?

Tags: highlander, highlander-franchise

Leaving aside "Highlander II: The Quickening" due to its continuity controversies, is there a clear and unambiguous implication in any of the "Highlander" movies that MacLeod is The One remaining Immortal with the rest of them dead (with the possible exception that one remaining hidden villain is frozen somewhere for the sake of the sequel movie)?

Comment: Um, "There can be only one"? :P I do not acknowledge the existence of any sequels or TV series!

Comment: Um. What is this movie #2 that you speak of? Everyone knows they skipped #2 out of superstition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Highlander

In the end of *Highlander* there's an extensive shot (in the Highlands) where Connor talks about the benefit of having received "the prize", e.g. that he's the last Immortal and has received the Quickening power from all the other Immortals who died before him.

I really don't see how his speech can be viewed any other way.

### Highlander III

There's a similar voiceover at the end of *Highlander III: The Sorceror* where Connor again talks about winning the prize (again) after killing the titular villain.

> **MCCLEOD:** *I'm at peace, **it's finally over.***

The original ending in the [draft script](https://web.archive.org/web/20111116210810/http://www.screenplays-online.de/download/36) was even clearer;

> **JENNIFER:** *What now?*
>
> **MCCLEOD:** *Now I can start to live.  To feel. To grow old and live each day without the promise of another.*

Comment: The question was about movies AFTER the first one.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile You should probably make that clear in the question, because the way I'm reading it, Highlander counts as one of "any of the Highlander movies".

Comment: Also, IIRC, Highlander III was basically a remake of Highlander I, lightly reskinned. I suspect that if Connor makes this speech in the end of Highlander, there's an equivalent speech in Highlander III.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - That's not what the question says.

Comment: @Paul - There was indeed (see edit). For the record, I personally thought **Highlander II** was the better film out of the sequels. It had all kinds of weird sh*t going on, but it was at least consistent in its writing.

Answer (score 7):

In the original Highlander (which I happen to have watched last night), in the scene in the church, The Kurgan says "Kastagir is gone.  Only you and I remain."

Comment: Isn't Duncan MacLeod the last immortal at the end of "Highlander: Endgame"?

Comment: @bogus: Unfortunately not. Highlander: The Source had quite a few other Immortals. Having the game ever be fully "over" would ruin any chances they have of making more.

Comment: What is Highlander: The Source?